# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method in zero padding CAGAN

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

i have an error about TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method when running zero padding method in CA GAN (https://github.com/fei-hdu/ca-gan/tree/new_parsing)

This is the code that is error (in data.py line 149)

```
def zero_padding(img, size0, pad1, pad2):
zero_padding = np.zeros((img.shape[0], size0, size0), dtype=np.float32)
print('img.shape[0] = ', img.shape[0])
pad1 = pad1 / 2
pad2 = pad2 / 2
zero_padding[:, pad1:size0 - pad1, pad2:size0 - pad2] = img
return zero_padding
```

This is the error

zero_padding[:, pad1:size0 - pad1, pad2:size0 - pad2] = img
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

Comment: Can you provide a MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you @MatthewBorish

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer..

I just got it..

```
def zero_padding(img, size0, pad1, pad2):
zero_padding = np.zeros((img.shape[0], size0, size0), dtype=np.float32)
pad1 = int(pad1 / 2)
pad2 = int(pad2 / 2)
zero_padding[:, pad1:size0 - pad1, pad2:size0 - pad2] = img
return zero_padding
```

Thank you